# Why doesn't asserting CPACK_DEBIAN_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE result in a .ddeb file?

Tags: cmake, deb, cpack

I'm attempting to use `cpack` to create `.ddeb` files (containing debug symbol info) for my `cmake` based project using `set(CPACK_DEBIAN_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE ON)` and can't tell why I'm not getting a `.ddeb` file being produced alongside the `.deb` file that *is* being produced correctly.  The contents of `main.cpp` is minimal and unimportant; here's my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
  
set(TEST_CPACK_DDEB_VERSION 0.7.6)
set(PROJECT_NAME TestCPackDDEB)
set(TEST_CPACK_DDEB_PROJECT TestCPackDDEBProject)
project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION ${TEST_CPACK_DDEB_VERSION} LANGUAGES CXX)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

set(SOURCES main.cpp)
set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        DESTINATION /usr/bin)

export(PACKAGE ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "testcpackddeb")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT "L User <luser@gmail.com>")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION "Not just another generator")
set(CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL ON)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_COMPRESSION_TYPE "gzip")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_PRIORITY "optional")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_FILE_NAME DEB-DEFAULT)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE ON)
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "")
include(CPack)
```

I've tried this with both `cmake` versions 3.16.3 (ubuntu 20.04) and 3.19.1 but get identical outcomes.  Here's the sequence of commands I run:

```bash
mkdir build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
make -j 8
cpack -G DEB
```

Surely a separate `.ddeb` file should be created, since I sure don't see a `.debug` file in the `.deb` package (using `dpkg --contents`) ...

**Edit:** In `cmake` version 3.22.1 (ubuntu 22.04) this bug seems to be fixed; `.ddeb` files are now being generated yay!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's not a usage problem at all -- it's just an upstream bug, like, it's broken.

Comment: Did you open an issue on the `cmake` project for this? I am having the same issue. I got the latest cmake sources but it still does not work.

Comment: No, I was too mad ... shoulda done that, you're right.